# Resolving constraints in Prolog

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd

I am looking resources for learning resolving of constraints in Prolog. For example,

```
List=[X, Y, Z], List ins 1..4, X - Y #= Z.
```

Comment: This is incorrect Prolog syntax. `List[X, Y, Z]` is invalid as was commented on in your [previously posted problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173168/constraint-programming-in-swi-prolog).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand, your want to get concrete solutions (and not the domains). For this, use `label/1` or `labeling/2`, which will give all the explicit solutions (via backtracking). In SWI-Prolog, these predicates are documented here: [labeling/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=labeling/2) .

`label(List)` is equivalent to `labeling([],List)`.

For this simple example, `label(List)` would suffice:

?- List=[X, Y, Z], List ins 1..4, X - Y #= Z,label(List).

In general, you would benefit by reading the full documentation of [clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) (here for SWI-Prolog).

Comment: I am trying to figure out how Prolog work out the domains. Could you recommend some source to read more on it?

Comment: If you want a general descriptions how domains (as well as propagators etc) works, a full book on Constraint (Logic) Programming is probably best for describing this is some detail. Some books I like on this:

Rina Dechter: "Constraint Processing" (2003), Apt "Principles of Constraint Programming" (2003), Marriott & Stuckey "Programming with Constraints" (1998, a little old but still inspiring).